# Add elements to std::vector efficiently

Tags: c++, addition, stdvector

I am currently working on a small game in C++17.
To manage elements in the game, I use an ordinary std::vector, which is supposed to manage elements of my cEntity class type.

In the code I currently have it defined like this

```
std::vector<cEntity> gameEntities;
```

In the code I also have a function add(), which should add elements of type cEntity.

For example:

```
void addEntity(void)
{
   gameEntities.emplace_back( cEntity{"default values"});
}
```

Is that performant? I wonder if a cEntity is first created here using the stack and then copied into the vector?
Would it be better / more efficient if I didn't manage the specific objects at all, but Smart Pointers instead?

For example:

```
std::vector<std::unique_ptr<cEntity>> gameEntities;

void addEntity(void)
{
   gameEntities.emplace_back(std::make_unique<cEntity>("default values"));
}
```

Is it faster?
The object of type cEntity is created on the heap and only the unique pointer is stored in the vector using move() semantics?
I'm not sure about that...
With C++ it's always said that you should use the stack wherever possible...

Thank you for a little explanation.

Comment: Assuming that `cEntity` have a suitable constructor: `gameEntities.emplace_back("default values");`

Comment: Try `gameEntities.emplace_back("default values");` and let `emplace_back` create the object in-place. That's the different from `push_back`, which requires an already constructed object.

Comment: Does `cEntity` provide an efficient move constructor? Do you always work only with `cEntity` objects, or is some inheritance / class hierarchy involved?

Comment: Don't speculate - profile you app and you will see. It does mater how you using your cEntity. If this is pointer on reference implementation -  second approach is preferred, If this is small structure - first approach is better.

Comment: Nobody can better answer than benchmarking. My bet is that there won't be any significant difference on the total time.

Answer (score 2):

For performant insertion of many elements into a vector you should either reserve or resize (whichever is more appropriate) upfront to make enough space once and avoid frequent reallocations. Reallocation strategies of `std::vector` are good (resulting in amortized constant complexity), but sometimes you can do better.

Moreoever, `emplace_back` is to pass parameters that will be forwarded to the elements constructor so that the element can be constructed in place. When you call `emplace_back` with an element it is no more efficient than `push_back`. The real power of `emplace_back` is only used when you do not create the element outside the vector and then move it into the vector, but rather only let it be constructed in place.